# Can't store TagName positions in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which displays a story, with buttons at the button to go from page 1 to page 2 and 3 and vise versa, the story is in a one array position which i've sliced using a character length to fill out each page. The text which im appending to the paragraphs on each page contains  tags. Im trying to add tooltips for each bit of i've placed in bold tags. I'm trying to get all  on the page, log the x and y position and then create an element with the text which is needed for each  element. Here's an example of what my code looks like

```
 pageItemsArray = [
      ['The <b tooltip ="make: rennault">car</b> is a round <b tooltip ="name: oak">tree</b>.']
      ['make: rennault', 'name: oak']
 ]
```

note: tooltip="make: rennault" and tooltip="name: oak" is only there for people trying to solve this with css, and is not there for people trying to solve this with javascript, however it doensn't need to be removed

html :

```
 <p class="insertStoryPageHere"><p>
```

javascript:

```
 for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("b").length; i++) {
     /*run code for all tooltips here*/

 element = document.createElement("SPAN");
 element.innerHTML = pageItemsArray[1][i].toString();
 element.setAttribute("class", "tooltip");
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 

 x = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[i].offsetLeft; 
 y = document.getElementsByTagName("b")[i].offsetTop;

 element.setAttribute("left", x);
 element.setAttribute("top", y);

 }
```

However, the spans are positioned at the bottom of the page, and not anywhere near where they are meant to be.

Update: Still not answered :(

heres css for people trying to solve via css

```
 b:hover[tooltip]:before {
     content: attr(tooltip);
     position: absolute; 
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0rem;
     left: 0rem;
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: black; 
     color: white;
     border-radius: 5px;

 .insertStoryPageHere {
     position: relative;
     font-family: Proxima;
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 2em;
     height: 311px;
 }
```

The problem with the css solution is that the tooltips are moving the paragraph text on hover...

[What it looks like, the with the css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dVPw.png)

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName["b"]` should be `document.getElementsByTagName("b")`. Its a function not an array

Comment: Do you want to add the `<span>` to `insertStoryPageHere`? Because then you need to get a reference to it like `var paragraph = document.querySelector('.insertStoryPageHere');` and later `paragraph.appendChild(element);` instead of `document.body.appendChild(element);`. As now you are indeed adding your `<span>` to the bottom of `<body>`.

Comment: No just to the body, they will have a class which has display hidden and then im going to add is so that each seperate <b> on hiver displays its corresponding tooltip as block, the spans are on the page, but theyre just no where near where they're meant to be :/

Comment: You should have a unit on the left and top. We would need to see more CSS to make sure you have it in a correct.

Comment: How about posting a full [reprex] so we can run and see what is actually going on? As soon as I have something running I can watch I'll add a second solution tailored to what you need to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty CSS only solution. I simply added a `tooltip` attribute to `<b>` with some text (slightly different from your array, though). This should give you some direction. No need for a complicated construction with remembering positions and what all not. Keep things simple and save the headache for the really hard stuff.

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 5rem } /* some spacing */

p { position: relative } /* creat a stacking context */

b:hover[tooltip]:before {
    content: attr(tooltip);
    position: absolute; 
    /* position within parent stacking context (the <p>, default is <body>) */
    
    top: -2.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: black; color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>this is a text about <b tooltip="car brand">Renault</b> and how you can keep it running for <b tooltip="unit of time">years</b>
```

Comment: unfortunately im dealing with several arrays of stories, and thus im trying to create something that will do the hard work for me, adding a tooltip="info here" to each <b> will disrupt the way i want my js code to flow, I basically have a multi dimensional array set up like this... array = [[['story page title'],['story page text'],['question 1 about story','question 2 about story', 'question 3 about story'], ['3 possible list item answers', '3 possible list item answers', '3 possible list item answers'], ['tool tip1, tool tip 2..']] ['next story title..]] ... then these items fill out elemen

Comment: `pageItemsArray = [ ['The <b tooltip="renault">car</b> is a round <b tooltip="oak">tree</b>.']  ]` maybe?

Comment: So I just wanna be able to fill out that array[i][4] box with the tooltips in order and then append them and so thats why I'm looking for a js solution, that way its much easier to read and edit the stories and add new stories. Thanks for the CSS solution though!

Comment: Using your css solution just for theory sake though, at the moment with the code you've written, the tooltips are moving the text around it, its pushing the word underneath forward, is there a way to fix this Rene? Cheers, seems like a great solution via css

Comment: I got what you were looking for, you want  (google for) 'javascript insert string in string'. This will need some kind of parameter inside the 'receiving' string (in your case you are using `<b>`). I skipped that step altogether and put the 'tooltip' directly in the array element (in my head anyway). Regarding the movement: not in the snippet, right? Check the `position: relative` of the parent and maybe set `z-index: 1` on the `:before`. Default z-index is 0, but you want it over the parent.

Comment: Z-index doesn't work, the javascript inserts the strings fine and in my paragraph i've already <b> around the parts which are needed, all i need, is to figure out how to log the x and y's using javascript because using your way I think its impossible for it to not move the element :/

Comment: I would need to see how you implemented my CSS solution to be able to say something useful about that. And that it wouldn't work in your case, in all honesty, doubtful, it is a much used and proven use of displaying stuff on `:hover`.

Comment: b:hover[tooltip]:before {
    content: attr(tooltip);
    position: relative; 
    /* position within parent stacking context (the <p>, default is <body>) */
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 0rem;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: black; 
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

Comment: Yup, 'position: relative' should be on the parent like `.insertStoryPageHere { position: relative }` and the child (your `<b>`'s) shoud read `position: absolute`, like I showed in the answer. Logic: confine child behaviour to a parent location (instead of the entire document). So: position a child absolutely, but relative to parent. ([w3schools: CSS position Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp))